# Problematic make file for java

Tags: java, ant, makefile

```
JFLAGS = -d bin -cp lib/slick.jar:lib/lwjgl.jar

JC = javac

.SUFFIXES: .java .class

.java.class: $(JC) $(JFLAGS) src/$*.java

CLASSES = \
          Game.java \
          Block.java \
          BlockMap.java \

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

clean: $(RM) bin/*.class
```

My source files are in src/ and I want to the compiled files to be in bin/ . When I run make, it gives me this error

```
makefile:7: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.
```

Comment: How are you running it? And why are you using make? (IMO the `src/` part before the `$*` macro is probably causing an issue.)

Comment: I'm using the command "make". Would it be better to use ant ? I saw this [link](http://myweb.stedwards.edu/laurab/help/javamakefile.html) and decided to use make.

Comment: *I'd* use Ant, but that doesn't mean *you* should ;) I just think it's a lot easier, since it's meant for Java. The equivalent Ant file would be about the same size and complexity anyway.

Comment: Personally I'd use Maven because it deals with third-party libraries for you, but it's a bit of a difficulty cliff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
.java.class: $(JC) $(JFLAGS) src/$*.java
```

and here:

```
clean: $(RM) bin/*.class
```

These are no rules but commands. And commands must be on its own lines **with a tab at the beginning of the line**.

```
.java.class: 
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) src/$*.java

clean: 
    $(RM) bin/*.class
```

Not that this are all problems with Makefiles and Java in general and this Makefile in particular.

Comment: The previous error is gone, but there's a new error now.

$ make
make: *** No rule to make target `Game.class', needed by `classes'.  Stop.

Comment: That`s the part where I mentioned upcoming problems. Here the problem is that make works best only in the current directory, but in your layout the sources and the classes are not in the current directory. Make is a very bad fit for Java even for small projects
But even if you put your three files into the current directory, you will run into problems as soon as you want to put your classes into packages...

Comment: Thank you for the response, I'll try ant.

Comment: Fine :-) Make the word a better place without _make_ ;-)
And look at my other answer for a starter.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't know how to manage a `Makefile` there is no reason *NOT* to use a better tool. Here is a minimal Ant file which should do the job. And because Ant is designed for Java, most of the directory handling problems of Make simply don't exist.

As a bonus you can ask any Java developer for more help. Java developers and Makefile experts are a quite uncommon match in these days.

```
<project name="Game" default="classes">
    <target name="classes">
        <mkdir dir="bin" />
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="bin" 
            classpath="lib/slick.jar;lib/lwjgl.jar"
            includeantruntime="false"/>
    </target>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="bin" />
    </target>
</project>
```